# Trimming meta description appropriately

Tags: seo, meta-tags

I have a question regarding meta descriptions.

On pages other than the homepage, the meta description simply uses the post content (I'm using Wordpress). My question is, should I be trimming the content to 150 chars? That's what I normally do, and I even append a "..." to the end.

However I'm wondering if its more beneficial to forget about the 155 char limit to fit it perfectly in Google listings.

Any opinions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description is just one of the sources Google considers when deciding what goes in the search result snippet.

Saying that, it is the most often used source so can be worth filling in, as it gives you a better chance of controlling what gets displayed.

Don't worry about its exact length or if it is different. The key thing is you have the chance to create a great snippet that encourages people to click to your article.

I'd install an SEO plugin that lets you override a default description. Then do that for your most popular articles so you can fine tune that snippet.

p.s. Don't append the "...". Google does that for you if your description is too long.

Answer (score 1):

I think its okay. I don't know if they handle it as double content. For me it would be nicer to write a separate and real short intro with most important keywords that differs from content.

Otherwise you can leave out description on article pages and Google is picking an interesting part out by itself and this part is related to the users search terms, if I have seen this right?!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, ideally yes I'd make a custom description for all the posts - however there are too many! :) Is leaving the meta description out entirely an option then??

Comment: I think so. I've read about it some time ago, that the search engines take a snipped from the content, when no description is defined and meta-tag for robots contains noodp and noydir. Otherwise they look if the website is in this catalogs and fetch description from there. Yahoo did it once to one of my pages even though I had meta-tag description on the site. But was no problem, because description at ODP/dmoz was nearly the same.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281172/it-is-good-to-use-other-and-other-description-meta-tag-for-all-pages-on-the-same) is another good post on the same topic.

Answer (score 0):

Also worth considering that the new style google site links lauinched within the last few weeks put an emphasis on the first circa 30 chars of the meta description.