# Is it better to use same or an alternative description meta tag for pages on the same domain?

Tags: html, seo, meta-tags

Lets say I have a site for a product. Site have three menus: Main,Product,Contact

It is a good idea to each one have its own `<meta name="description"` tags with description for its content? Basically this is a SEO question. Does it have any affect on SEO? Or it is better to use one static description for all the site?

For example:
**Main:** 
`<meta name="description" content="This is my product site, you can check my product or contact me" />`

**Product:** 
`<meta name="description"content="This is the product I sell. Get info about its abilities etc." />`

**Contact:** 
`<meta name="description" content="Find my product on facebook, twitter. Call me or write e-mail" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is a good idea, hence SEO, just for semantic reasons it's good to refer to each page with it's content and context.. Besides that searching on Google will show the description directly under the link, theres no sense in refering to three pages with the same description.. So yes describe each page differntly but always into context..

Comment: Google will only use the explicitly declared meta description if it believes that it's a good match for the search query. The snippets will actually change based on the search conducted. There's more information on this [here](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35624#1) and [here](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2007/09/improve-snippets-with-meta-description.html)

Answer (score 1):

It is best to a have a different META description on each page - relevant to the page contents. However, this won't affect your search engine ranking directly, but it could affect the descriptive text the user sees in the SERPs, so yes it does affect SEO (although indirectly) as it could determine whether the user clicks your link or not.

You should certainly not have the same META description on every page. The META description should reflect the contents of that page.